# trouble in installation of mongodb for node.js on windows10 with node version 14.4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, npm

I need to install mongodb for node.js. but it showing the following error.

```
C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp>node -v v14.4.0

C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp>npm install mongodb 
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp\package.json' 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp\package.json' 
npm WARN node_db_exp No description 
npm WARN node_db_exp No repository field. 
npm WARN node_db_exp No README data 
npm WARN node_db_exp No license field.

mongodb@4.4.1 added 20 packages from 59 contributors and audited 20 packages in 9.832s
3 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

could anyone help in this? I am using node annd mongodb for the first time by following the tutorials at w3schools.com

Comment: Did you install MongoDB itself? https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

Comment: You didn't [create](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) a [package.json file](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json/).

Comment: i have created one using the command 'npm init' as guided

Answer (score 0):

There is no error. It's just a warning. You have successfully installed the mongodb driver.

Comment: Yes, it is installed. But when I try to use it , it gives error as follows...

Comment: You can use "npm init" command to create automatically package.json

Comment: Can you share your code? What error does it give when you use it?

Comment: Could you please guide me why I am receiving the following error...

Comment: var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
//Create a database named "mydb":
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});

Comment: What does it output when you run this code?

Comment: I am unable to post the error as the comment limit binds. .. When I execute  the above code using 'npm demo_create_mongo_db.js.. it shows error

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: can you try this "node demo_create_mongo_db.js"

Comment: C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp>node demo_create_mongo_db
C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:504
                    throw error;
                    ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\react_native_node_app\node_db_exp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:312:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)

Comment: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}

Comment: I have used 'node demo_create_mongo_db.js' and 'node demo_create_mongo_db' both one by one but getting the same response as shared above..

Comment: I think mongodb server is not working. Did you install mongodb community server? and are you sure it's working? You can check the task manager. "mongod.exe" should be running

Comment: You can also check services for mongodb.

Comment: yes, It could be the reason. ...

Comment: I have checked the task manager . There is no process of mongod.exe.. could you please guide where can i check the services ?

Comment: press Windows + R then type "services.msc". find the mongo service and start

Comment: I have not found mongo services in the service list too...

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this issue by installing the setup of mongodb manually and now the commands are working properly. Perhaps! node module is not sufficient to run the commands.

D:\react_native_node_app\example_node_files>node App.js
Database created!

C:\Users\Radhaswami\node_db_exp>node demo_create_mongo_db.js
Database created!

thank you everyone for your precious time and guidelines. I have installed from the link https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community suggested by Mr. Wernfried Domscheit.